# Including Null values in a joined table

Tags: sql, join, null

I am trying to join two tables and include all of the values even if they are null. I cant figure out how to include these values that are missing for the min(price) and max(price) that are null. I am thinking that I need a where clause but everything I write I get an sql error such as where min(price) is null and min(price) not null. This is what I have for the query so far:

```
select items.barcode, iname as item_name, weight
, min(price)
, max(price)
, min(quantity)
, max(quantity)
, sum(quantity)
from items 
join order_lines on items.barcode = order_lines.barcode
group by barcode;
```

I also want the lowest/highest quantity to be 0 if the value is null which it is and I am not sure how to fix that after I use a left join to solve that first problem above^^

Comment: Use a `LEFT JOIN` instead of `JOIN`.

Comment: thank you this worked! but if I want a lowest/highest quantity to say 0 instead of null how would I fix that then?

Comment: Look into `coalesce`  function to handle null

Comment: or possibly the NVL function